# Required inputs disable form submission immedietly

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some form submission, and upon submission, I want to display an error message in case the vote is not there. The thing is, my error message is not showing up, because upon submitting the form, I immediately get the required fields highlighted when they are empty. But I want them all in the same time to be highlighted. What can be a problem? Here is my form submission function

```
const form = document.getElementById("registerForm");
  form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("hey");

    const errorMessage = document.querySelector(".required_fields_market");
    const requiredFields = form.querySelectorAll(".required"); // Assuming required fields have class 'required'
    let isFormValid = true;

    // Check favorite buttons
    const favoriteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon-favorite-filled");
    if (favoriteButtons.length === 0) {
      errorMessage.style.display = "block"; // Show error message if no favorite is selected
      isFormValid = false;
    } else {
      errorMessage.style.display = "none"; // Hide error message if a favorite is selected
    }

    // Check each required field
    requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
      if (!field.value.trim()) {
        field.classList.add("is-invalid"); // Add 'is-invalid' class if field is invalid
        isFormValid = false;
      } else {
        field.classList.remove("is-invalid"); // Remove 'is-invalid' class if field is valid
      }
    });

    // Proceed only if form is valid
    if (isFormValid) {
      const formData = new FormData(form);

      if (favoriteSightseeingInput.value.trim() !== "") {
        formData.set("vote_name", favoriteSightseeingInput.value.trim());
      }

      fetch(form.action, {
        method: form.method,
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          // Optional: Handle successful form submission response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
          // Optional: Handle form submission error
        });
    }
  });
```

should i add click event on the button to check validation here, or is it maybe some other script that is preventing me from doing that?

Comment: This is [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm) behavior, if HTML validation fails, the form submission algorithm is cancelled, and JS listeners are never called (item 5.3 in the algorithm description). I'm afraid the only you can do is to drop the `requred` attributes, and use `data-required` instead (update your script also to collect `data-required` elements).

Comment: It looks like I've missed the fact that you're collecting `required` class, then the only you need to do is to remove the actual `required` attributes from the form control elements.